# Visited links in the footer have wrong color

Tags: bug, design

Visited links should have the same color as non-visited links. It looks uneven like these and the different style has no usability purpose in this context.

It happens in both main and meta.

```
a:visited {
  color: #676767;
}

a {
  color: #000000;
}
```

-- https://cdn.sstatic.net/skeptics/all.css?v=3e18be03edba

[image]